# Devise + Omniauth in a mountable engine : undefined method `user_omniauth_authorize_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

i have been trying to set up my engine with devise+omniauth for authentication. Everything seems OK so far, except when i configure an omniauth provider, such as twitter, the partial devise/shared/_links.erb ( which i have installed/copied to my engine ) invokes omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) which in turn attempts to call #{resource_name}_omniauth_authorize_path that does not seem to exist. ( undefined method `user_omniauth_authorize_path' )

Here's my (really really short) routes.rb, devise.rb and the model, user.rb:
https://gist.github.com/pgn84/5944323

All of these are in the engine. The host app only mounts the engine in routes.rb

Any idea what i could be missing here? Where should user_omniauth_authorize_path be defined?

Thanks!

ps: i'm on rails 4.0.0 and devise 3.0.0.rc

Comment: Hi, I have exactly same problem :(

Answer (score 2):

You should call it like that

```
my_engine.user_omniauth_authorize_path
```